# My AudioPlayer is not working. can't understand this

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My audioPlayer is not working.  I can't seem to understand why.  I am a newbie and don't have much experience with swift.  When I run, I am getting the println("audioPlayer not created") message.  FilePath, FilePathUrl and mp3 have been confirmed and valid.

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("crankringtone", ofType: "mp3"){
        var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
    } else {
        println("file path is empty")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    // here you can check if the player was successfully created
    if var audioPlayer = audioPlayer {
        // here you can check if your player is playing
        if audioPlayer.playing {
            //if playing lets pause it
            audioPlayer.pause()
        } else {
            //if plaused lets play it
            audioPlayer.play()
        }

    } else {
        println("audioPlayer not created")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to understand why.

Then write code that helps you understand. Your code is an odd mix of checking for errors and ignoring errors. Look at these two lines:

```
var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
```

The first of those lines can fail - you can get nil. The second of those lines can fail - you can get an error, which would be reported to you if you passed an NSErrorPointer as the second parameter. Yet you are ignoring all of that and not checking for errors.

So your audio player is not being created and you are not noticing, because you are not checking for errors along the way.

Another odd thing about your code is that you do a `pathForResource` and then try to convert that to a URL. That's nutty. If you wanted a URL (and you do), why didn't you do a `URLforResource` to start with?

So basically the problem here is that you have structured your code to be error-prone and opaque to those errors. Write code that *explores* each step along the way so that you *know* what's happening. Or just use the debugger and step through the code, examining the variables as you go. You'll soon understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

1) @Matt explained why you are not initialising properly. You can check that you  do not have an instance of audioPlayer by putting a breakpoint on that line and hove over audioPlayer on the right. If there is no instance, it will say nil, and there is no player to play the song.

```
if var audioPlayer = audioPlayer
```

2) You should not declare a local variable with the same name as instance variable. How should later the compiler know which one do you mean?

3) You condition is logically wrong. You are checking whether you assigned something to something. Do not confuse assignment = and comparison ==

4) You have to call audioplayer.prepareToPlay() and then you have to call audioPlayer.play() to play something. The first tis to repopulate the audio buffers,. the second is to play the content. I don't see any of those methods anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the var declaration to:

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer? = nil
```

and down there just use

```
if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer {...}
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var playPause: UIButton!

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let fileUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("crankringtone", withExtension:"mp3") {
            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileUrl, error: nil)
        } else {
            println("could not find bundle file")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func playAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        // here you can check if the player was successfully created
        if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer {
            // here you can check if your player is playing
            if audioPlayer.playing {
                //if playing lets pause it
                playPause.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                audioPlayer.pause()
            } else {
                //if plaused lets play it
                playPause.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                audioPlayer.play()
            }
        } else {
            println("audioPlayer not created")
        }
    }
}
```